# How do I get Hudson to stop escaping parts of my shell script?

Tags: hudson

I would like to have a shell script that copies some logs from a part of my system to the hudson workspace so I can archive them.

So right now I have

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
cp /directory/structure/*.log .
```

This is kind enough to be changed to

```
cp '/directory/structure/*.log' .
```

Which of course is not found since I don't have a file named *.log.

So how do I get this script to work?

**EDIT**
So I left out the part that I was using sudo cp /path/*.log, because I didn't think that would matter.  Of course it does and sudo is the issue not hudson.

Comment: I've seen jenkins do this to anything `*`'s in jenkins shells, `sudo` or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo bash -c "cp /directory/structure/*.log"
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple answer would be to have the shell script in a separate file, and have hudson call that.

Comment: That would be my last resort in this case.  I'd like to be able to make changes to the script from off-site and our permissions are such that the webpage is much easier to get to then ssh'ing to the box.

Comment: If you're doing more than just the cp, then you could isolate just the cp into a separate script and then you retain flexibility

Answer (score 0):

Throwing it out there, but haven't had a chance to try it in Hudson (so I don't know how it gets quoted):

```
for f in /directory/structure/*.log ; do
    cp $f .
done
```

In my simple test in a bash shell, different quoting options produce either one or multiple invocations of the copy command (either with all matching files or one at a time), but they all manage to do the copy successfully.

Comment: Doesn't work.  Hudson turns it into: for f in '/directory/structure/*.log' ; do

Comment: @Rob_Spieldenner OK. For me, $f now contains the quoted string and the shell performs the glob in the cp command.